# Ext.ux.Image : Cannot read property 'dom' of undefined

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I need a real `<img>` HTML tag in my view Sencha.

I've retrieved this code from the official doc :

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.Image', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component', // subclass Ext.Component
    alias: 'widget.managedimage', // this component will have an xtype of 'managedimage'
    autoEl: {
        tag: 'img',
        src: Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL,
        cls: 'my-managed-image'
    },

    // Add custom processing to the onRender phase.
    // Add a ‘load’ listener to the element.
    onRender: function() {
        this.autoEl = Ext.apply({}, this.initialConfig, this.autoEl);
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.el.on('load', this.onLoad, this);
    },

    onLoad: function() {
        this.fireEvent('load', this);
    },

    setSrc: function(src) {
        if (this.rendered) {
            this.el.dom.src = src;
        } else {
            this.src = src;
        }
    },

    getSrc: function(src) {
        return this.el.dom.src || this.src;
    }
});
```

When i try to do *setSrc*, I get this error : **Cannot read property 'dom' of undefined**

Comment: I'm not sure where you got that code from, but why don't you use the Ext.Img class instead? Docs here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Img Run this fiddle for an example: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#se9pt

Comment: Yep, I know Ext.Img, but I need a real img node because of performance of ratio calculation.

Comment: That code you posted does not reflect a real image node. Also, it won't work with ST2, either way I struggle to understand what you want a 'real image node'. Why can't you use a container component and let the image adapt to the size of the container? You mentioned you got this from the offical docs, can you let us know where exactly you got this from?

Comment: There : http://www.sencha.com/learn/components/

Comment: I think they used it as an example but it might be out-of-date (published: Apr 26, 201 / updated: Jul 11, 2011).

Comment: That page mentions it's only relevant to Ext JS, 4.x and thus will not work with ST2. Either way, it looks like it does the same thing as Ext.Img.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is from Ext.Js 4.x docs. You should use sencha touch 2 docs.
Please compare: 
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Component

and

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Component

They are different.

As i understand you need real < img > tag in your view. If you use Ext.Img it will create a div container with background-image.
I know two ways:

1. set up tpl and data property.

```
Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
  config: {
    tpl: '',
    data: {
      url: 'http://example.com/pics/1.png',
      imgClass: 'my-class'
    }
  }
});
```

1. set html config.

```
Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
    config: {
    html: ' <img class="my-class" src="http://example.com/pics/1.png">'
    }
});
```